# apply 3d animation to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I'm struggling with animations and can't find anything like i want. I would like to apply a 3d rotation to a view. Like a cube rotation, the view should have two images, and rotate from one to other like iphone notification animation. Animation i want is like this one here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBgVbzBJqDc

I don't think even one way of how to do this, so any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply a 3D animation to a view by setting a CATransform3D with the transform on the views layer. The rotation will look very flat without any perspective so you should set an appropriate value for the third row and forth column of the transform matrix.

**ObjC:**

```
CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotation.m34 = -1.0/500.0;
rotation = CATransform3DRotate(rotation, M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
myView.layer.transform = rotation;
```

**Swift:**

```
var rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
rotation.m34 = CGFloat(-1.0/500.0)
firstView.layer.transform = rotation;
```

You would give the two views suitable values for the angle and position them where they should be on screen.

To make it look like a cube rotation you could also translate the layers half the width of the cubes side (so that it doesn't rotate around the center) before rotating the transform matrix.

```
rotation = CATransform3DTranslate(rotation, 0.0, 0.0, sideOfCube/2.0);
```

Comment: this is nice! do you know how to change the direction of the rotation?

Comment: Either animate to a negative angle or change the animation axis from z to -z by changing the last parameter from 1.0 to -1.0

Comment: I've tried it like this, but this doesn't change anything. Am I doing something wrong?

 `CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DIdentity;
                         rotation.m34 = -1.0/500.0;
                         rotation = CATransform3DRotate(rotation, M_PI, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
                         _d3RightView.layer.transform = rotation;`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that code but a rotation of π is the same for both directions (halfway around). Try something like 3/4π i.e. `3.0*M_PI_4`